# How do I make spelling corrector using txt file

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here's my txt file, called it `replacer.txt`

```
keyword_origin, keyword_destinantion
topu,topup
atmstrbca,atm bca
```

Here's what I want

```
id keyword
1  transfer atmstrbca
2  topu bank
3  topup bank
```

My expected output

```
id keyword
1  transfer atm bca
2  topup bank
3  topup bank
```

What I did is

```
df['keyword'].str.replace("atmstrbca","atm bca")
df['keyword'].str.replace("topu","topup")
```

The output is

```
id keyword
1  transfer atm bca
2  topup bank
3  topupp bank
```

My Idea is using text `replacer.txt` to do this since the list is more tahn 100 keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dictionary from first file and split values by whitespace and use `get` for replace:

```
d = dict(zip(df1.keyword_origin, df1.keyword_destinantion))
#alternative
#d = df1.set_index('keyword_origin')['keyword_destinantion'].to_dict()
df2['keyword'] = df2['keyword'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([d.get(y, y) for y in x.split()]))
print (df2)
   id           keyword
0   1  transfer atm bca
1   2        topup bank
2   3        topup bank
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.replace` with a callable:

```
In [11]: d = {"atmstrbca": "atm bca", "topu": "topup"}  # all the typos

In [12]: regex = r'\b' + '|'.join(d.keys()) + r'\b'

In [13]: df['keyword'].str.replace(regex, lambda x: d[x.group()], regex=True)
Out[13]:
0    transfer atm bca
1          topup bank
2          topup bank
Name: keyword, dtype: object
```

---

You can make the dict from the other DataFrame, e.g. via:

```
dict(zip(df_replacer.keyword_origin, df_replacer.keyword_destinantion))
```